# If an ODE has a unique strong solution, all weak solutions must coincide with the strong solution?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider a system of ordinary differential equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d f}{dt}=F(f(t)) \text{ with } f(0)=v
\end{equation}
where $f:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector-valued function on a compact interval and $F :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed to be smooth (not necessarily linear). $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is some specified vector.

Let us assume that the above ODE has a unique strong solution on whole of $[0,T]$, denoted as $f_{str}$.

Now, I am aware that a weak solution is defined to be any $f:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
\begin{equation}
-\int_{0}^T f(t) \cdot g'(t) dt = \int_0^T F(f(t))g(t) dt+v \cdot g(0)
\end{equation}
for any differentiable $g : [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $g(T)=0$.

Now, I wonder if $f$ is a weak solution satisfying the above formula, then if it is in fact equal to the unique strong solution $f_{str}$ and thus differentiable with respect to $t$.

I suspect this is the case, but I am not sure..Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I suspect we need uniqueness of a weak solution for this statement to hold true, and for this we might need some more regularity properties of $F$, c.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922710/existence-theorem-on-weak-solutions-of-ordinary-differential-equations?rq=1.